# JPA Entity best way for ManyToOne Bidirectional Relationship with Foreign Key

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Considering the below table structure and relation.

```
Teacher
id(pk),
tname,
subject_id(fk),
subject_name

Subject
sid(pk),
sname,
subject_learning_curve
```

TEACHER(owner of relationship) to SUBJECT Many to One , bidirectional relationship

I used persistence tool window [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-persistence-tool-window.html#a5831) in intellij . Which based on the data source generates the Entities automatically for all the relationships in DB.

In the entity it is generated like this

```
@Entity
//using lombok for getters and setters
public class TEACHER{
     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String tname;
    private long subject_id;
    private String subject_name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id",referencedColumnName="sid")
    private Subject subjectBySid;    //is this fine to have a reference like this
}
```

OR 2nd approach below

```
@Entity
    //using lombok for getters and setters
    public class Teacher{
         
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private String tname;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id",referencedColumnName="sid")
        private Subject subject;    //or just this it will suffice all use case,like if i just want to read Teacher data and just the sid not the whole subject row
    }
```

Similarly Subject will also have reference pointing back to Teacher table.

Based on below points ,can someone provide insights.

1. Which is ideal and correct out of the above two ways of writing a entity.
2. From Hibernate and JPA perspective which is more efficient.
3. Will there be any difference on the sql generated based on what approach i chose to write my entity.
4. If i take 2nd approach will it be more easier to query and save records to DB or to retrieve.
5. Would the subject_id in TEACHER have value when i get the data in Entity or it will be just a reference named subject,and i would not get that specific field in TEACHER.subject_id or `@JoinColumn(name = "subject_id",referencedColumnName="sid")` annotation will take care of that and it should have value in TEACHER.subject_id

Comment: Just for the sake of clarification. Are you sure that you would like to have ```Teacher``` and ```Subject``` mapped as many to one and not vice versa? Usually ```Teacher``` lectures several subjects.

Comment: yes, it is just for example no specific logic behind that. You can think of any ManyToOne Relationship and Many side is the owner of relationship.

Comment: any more views?

Comment: I'd definitely opt for second approach - I've never seen a first one frankly speaking in any project. First one contains redundant information, (it violates one of the DB normal forms - 2NF I reckon). If you take first approach, you'll have to synchronize redundant data - no sense. With two separate tables/entities it is more natural first of all and you loose nothing from the performance point of view, because you will have index on the ```teacher``` foreign key in ```subject``` table.

Answer (score 0):

Below are my answers and suggestions on your questions:

*1.Which is ideal and correct out of the above two ways of writing a entity.*

> Approach 2 is correct way of writing an enitiy. Once you have defined  `@ManyToOne` relation with another entity,no need to define columns specific to that entity.

*2. From Hibernate and JPA perspective which is more efficient.*

> **JPA** is the specification for management of relational data in Java and **Hibernate** is the Object-Relational Mapping(ORM) tool that saves the state of objects into DB. Simply put, Hibernate is the implementation of JPA. Hence, comparing them should not be a question. You can compare Hibernate with other ORM tools that can be used with Spring framework like iBatis, EclipseLink,etc.

*3. Will there be any difference on the sql generated based on what approach i chose to write my entity.*

> No ,generated SQL will be the same. But, to generate that SQL, you can use different approaches like `@NativeSqlQuery`, `Hibernate Query Language(HQL)`,etc.

*4.If i take 2nd approach will it be more easier to query and save records to DB or to retrieve.*

> You should definitely use 2nd approach for clear,staright-forward and relational approach. 1st approach is wrong to its core if you take about the principles of object-oriented language and relational database management. No need to create extra columns,code,entity properties, and other mistakes when you can easily link them through mapping.

*5.Would the subject_id in TEACHER have value when i get the data in Entity or it will be just a reference named subject,and i would not get that specific field in TEACHER.subject_id or @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id",referencedColumnName="sid") annotation will take care of that and it should have value in TEACHER.subject_id*

> In your DB,you should have a column `subject_id` in your `Teacher` table that will be a **foreign key** and references `sid` column of `Subject` table. This happens at DB end.
> At your Object-oriented end (Spring), you can use create object reference for `Subject` to map with `Student` or you can directly use field `subject_id` in your *HQL or NativeQuery* to perform DB operations and persist the data.
> Hence, you will get `subject_id` in your `Teacher` entity.

Comment: I did not mean hibernate vs jpa, what i mean was when i query the `@Repository`class or when i Insert data to any of those table i need to write code and that mostly depend on what i have in `@Entity` which is JPA. So based on how i write my `@Entity` it can make me write more or less code. Then comes Hibernate which will generate the queries for same

Comment: OK, well in that case, Approach 2 is more efficient as there is no need to declare new properties,write their getters/setters and persist them for subject-related fields like subject_id & subject_name as you have already mapped `Teacher` entity with `subject` entity.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please upvote and aceept if the answer is useful to help me grow in the community.
Do let me know if you need an example to understand how to fetch and manipulate the relation using entity as well as `subject_id`.

Comment: `Hence, you will get subject_id in your Teacher entity`  I can understand if i have reference to student i would obviously have student id in that reference but what am trying to figure out is whetheri will get `TEACHER.subject_id` as a field in the Teacher JPA entity

Comment: Yes, you will get the `subject_id` for `Teacher` entity. To confirm that, check your corresponding DB table. You will find the column.